# Python speech_recognition can't not read wav file

Tags: python, speech-recognition, wav

I want to use `recognize_google` to analyze the number in the wav file

```py
 try:
   temp = r.recognize_google(".//splitAudio//split.wav",language="zh-TW")
   print("You have said \n" + temp )
   print("Audio Recorded Successfully \n ")
 except Exception as e:
   print("Error :  " + str(e))
```

but I got the following error: `Error :  audio_data must be audio data`

I have found this answer for a while, but I don't figure out.

Who can help me,i really appreciate it,thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have time to install stuff and find a WAV file but here's what [The Ultimate Guide To Speech Recognition With Python](https://realpython.com/python-speech-recognition/#using-record-to-capture-data-from-a-file) says re "Using record() to Capture Data From a File"

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
harvard = sr.AudioFile('harvard.wav')
with harvard as source:
    audio = r.record(source)

r.recognize_google(audio)
```